# Real-valued matrices and their eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Why are the eigenvalues of the symmetric matrix $A^TB^TBA$ equal to the eigenvalues of the matrix $B^TBAA^T$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ and $B$ is either:

$B = \begin{pmatrix} {1}, {0}, {0} \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} {1}, {0}, {0} 
\\
{0}, {0}, {1}\end{pmatrix}$ or $I_3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the nonzero eigenvalues of $CD$ and $DC$ are always the same for any matrices $C$ and $D$ that can be multiplied in both directions.
See e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial#Characteristic_polynomial_of_a_product_of_two_matrices).
This is just the case $C = A^T$, $D = B^T B A$.